# How to derive Mean of Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: neural-networks, normal-distribution, mean, batch-normalization

How to derive Mean of [Truncated Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) which is **equation 17** below ?

[image]

Note: Image screenshot is taken from [L1-Norm Batch Normalization for Efficient Training of Deep Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.09769.pdf#page=3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expectation of $Y=|X-\mu|$ doesn't depend on $\mu$, because the expression inside the absolute parentheses has zero mean. Direct derivation of $\mu_Y$ follows as below:

Let $f(x)=ce^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, where $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}$; then,
$$\begin{align}\mu_Y&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty|x-\mu|f(x)dx=2\int_{\mu}^{\infty}(x-\mu)f(x)dx\\&=2c\int_\mu^\infty (x-\mu) e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}dx\underbrace{=}_{u={\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}}2c\int_0^\infty e^{-u}\sigma^2du\\&=2c\sigma^2=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma\end{align}$$

If you're interested in the expected value for the PDF $f_Z(z)=2ce^\frac{-(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}, z\in [\mu,\infty)$, (i.e. half normal folded over $\mu$, not $0$) it also can be found very similarly by just variable changes.

Comment: In R: `set.seed(822); mean(abs(rnorm(10^7, 0, 10)))` returns 7.978422 and `10*sqrt(2/pi)` returns 7.978846, about the expected number of places of agreement.

Comment: you have a typo in the variable u during change of variable, where it should not have the negative sign. Otherwise, everything else looks correct to me...

Comment: @kevin, yes I removed the minus sign; thank you.

Comment: Wait, I need to clarify how is [Half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) different compared to [folded normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution) as mentioned in the document screenshot ?

Comment: half-normal is a special case of folded normal, where the RV inside the absolute value is zero mean.